# Проблемы со звуком

Tags: windows

На компе все аудио и видео плееры говорят голосами Чипа и Дэйла((( Как это устранить?

Comment: Устанавливали какие-нибудь "супер-мега-улучшалки" звука?

Answer (score 1):

В настройках плеера поищи там есть снижение голоса повышение.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает что это включен так называеммый "еффект звука".
Как правило в трее (там где часы) есть программа для настройки звуковой карты (SoundMax и т.д)
Там поищите еффекты, если они включены - выключите их.